# Binding from DependencyProperty of a UserControl not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, dependency-properties

I have a `UserControl` with one `DependencyProperty` which sets **in codebehind** (I guess this may be a source of my problem, but still don't know what to do):

**UserControl**

```
 public partial class MyControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyControl),
       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("",FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text"));}
    }

    public static string GetText(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(TextProperty);
    }

    public static void SetText(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    private void ChangeText()
    {
        Text="some value";
    }
}
```

In my View.xaml I use this control like this:

```
 <MyControl Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

And the Text property in my ViewModel:

```
 private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text= value; InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text"));}
    }
```

**The problem:**
Text property in the ViewModel never gets updated; when use binding with a regular control like TextBox, all works perfect; if I set Text in XAML, Text propery of UserControl updates.
What I did wrong?

---

**UPDATE**
My issue was that I have set DataContext explicitly on MyControl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is in your Binding:

```
Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

**`Text` property is in your ViewModel but you are referring to itself by using RealtiveSource to point back to self. So, it's binding Text DP with itself.**

If you have set `DataContext` of your control, it will automatically inherit `DataContext` from parent. So, you don't need `RelativeSource` at all.

It simply should be:

```
Text="{Binding Text}"
```

---

**Few points more (but not related to your issue)**:

- Since you target to use this property from within control, so go for normal DP instead of attached property.
- Since at time of registration, you have set it to bind TwoWay by default. No need to explicitly do that at time of binding.
- Remove InvokePropertyChanged call from your DP wrapper setter. Setter won't be called from XAML and also DP is already PropertyChanged aware.

---

**UPDATE**

In case `DataContext` of `MyControl` is set to instance of another class, above approach will search for `Text` property in MyControl DataContext.

You can pass DataContext of parent control (StackPanel in your case) like this:

```
Text="{Binding DataContext.Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                 Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel}}"
```

Comment: this is not work too...:( when I change property in MyControl by calling ChangeText() it is not changes Text property of a ViewModel

Comment: Are you sure you have set DataContext to point to ViewModel in your containing control of MyControl (may be window, another userControl etc.). Also haven't you set DataContext explicitly on MyControl? Can you look for any binding error in output window? Does getter of `Text` property in ViewModel gets hit on load?

Comment: `<StackPanel>
            <MyControl Text="{Binding Text}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
        </StackPanel>`  when I have this TextBlock, getter of Text property is called. With only MyControl it is never called. I'm confused

Comment: with `<MyControl Text="blah"/>` the property in MyControl updates

Comment: If with `Textblock` Text getter is getting called. Then only issue I can think of is you have set `DataContext` on MyControl explicitly. I will update with another approach in answer.

Comment: Oh God, I really set DataContext explicitly for binding some MyControl commands! Now everything works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have registered your property as attached, yet you are also using it as a regular DependencyProperty. I think that the xaml parser gets confused. Decide which one you want to use.

Comment: Attached property is registered against MyControl only so it can be used like OP is doing.

Comment: Register is anyway the correct way of declaring it.

Comment: I also meant to remove the Get/SetText methods.